# apply @Valid on RequestBody in Spring MVC where type of object is String

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I wanted a controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = RETRIEVE)
public List<String> getAll(@RequestBody @Valid @Size(min = 1) List<String> numbers) {
    return service.getAll(numbers);
}
```

I can't create a new object and add variable List numbers, as that will break the contract. Is it possible to achieve in spring boot using @Valid?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30558557/5039001

Comment: none of the answer from that thread actually work for my problem.